# Is exponential affinity matrix positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, data-analysis, positive-semidefinite

An $n\times n$ exponential affinity matrix $W$ is defined as:

$w_{ij}=e^{-d^2(x_i, x_j)}$,

where $d(x_i, x_j)$ is the distance between $x_i\in \mathbb R^m$ and $x_j\in \mathbb R^m$, which measures the similarity between $x_i$ and $x_j$. For example, using L2 norm: $d(x_i, x_j)=||x_i -x_j||$.

Is $W$ positive definite or positive semidefinite or neither? How to prove it?

Answer (score 0):

It is well-known that the Gaussian kernel $\Phi(x)=\exp(-\alpha\|x\|_2^2)$ is strictly positive for all $\alpha>0$ (see the example on p.12 of [this handout](http://www.math.iit.edu/%7Efass/603_ch2.pdf) for instance). Therefore the answer to your question is "yes" when $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|_2$.

However, the answer is negative for a general distance function $d$. Here is a random counterexample: let the distance matrix between four points $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and $x_4$ be
$$
D=\left(d(x_i,x_j)\right)_{i,j\in\{1,2,3,4\}}=\pmatrix{0&1&0.7&0.7\\ 1&0&0.3&0.7\\ 0.7&0.3&0&1\\ 0.7&0.7&1&0}.
$$
One may verify that the $d$ defined above does satisfy the triangle inequality. However, numerically we have $\det\left(\exp\left(-D\circ D\right)\right)=-0.056442<0$. Therefore $\exp\left(-D\circ D\right)$ is not positive semidefinite.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a self-contained proof for the case $d(x, y)=||x-y||_2$? The Gaussian kernel is strictly positive, then why the matrix W is PSD?

Comment: @yzxhd When the kernel function is strictly positive, the matrix is positive definite when all $x_i$s are distinct, or singular and positive semidefinite otherwise. For proofs, see the handout or books on statistical learning. Some relevant keywords are "completely monotone function", "Bochner's theorem" and "Schoenberg interpolation theorem".